How to return name, given an ID Number from same dataset?
I want to write a query that returns names and their best friends name from the table below:
Example FRIEND Table:



FriendID
Name
BestFriendID




1
Abby



2
Bob
3


3
Carl
2



Expected Output:



Name
Bestfriend




Abby



Bob
Carl


Carl
Bob



My Code so far:
SELECT A.Name, B.BestFriendID AS Bestfriend
FROM FRIEND A, FRIEND B
WHERE A.FriendID = B.BestFriendID;

The problem is the output returns the ID of the original friend:



Name
Bestfriend




Abby
1


Bob
2


Carl
3



So what am I missing? Any help would be appreciated

Bad habits to kick: using old-style JOINs - that old-style comma-separated list of tables style was replaced with the proper ANSI JOIN syntax in the ANSI-92 SQL Standard (more than 30 years ago!) and its use is discouraged

You're close! You need to join the tables on the BestFriendID and then select the friend's name, you forgot that - try this:
SELECT A.Name, B.Name AS Bestfriend
FROM FRIEND A
LEFT JOIN FRIEND B ON A.BestFriendID = B.FriendID;

